# PayPal was error when using LIVE Mode Payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

When I using Sandbox mode it's work fine.

But when I switch to Live Mode error was happens.

```
{"response":{"name":"INSTRUMENT_DECLINED","details":[],"message":"The instrument presented  was either declined by the processor or bank, or it can't be used for this payment.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"51d8a0cb6f968","httpStatusCode":400},"httpStatusCode":400}
```

How can I solve this problem.
I use a Thailand Debit card to pay and have an enough money to pay.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this means your credit card was declined.  See [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/how-to/customize-flow/#manage-funding-source-failure) for more info.

Comment: That is it! But this card used to buy other thing in PayPal and this card was no problem at all. But I don't see this Error before.

Comment: How can I know an exactly reason?
"The transaction exceeds the card limit."is not a problem this case because a money is enough.

Comment: Essentially you'd have to contact the card issuer.  PayPal won't know why it was declined.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case it was because I did a lot of tests of payments and reversals in the same paypal`s account, with the same product. I think Paypal "blocked" my account and it starts to deny all of my payments.

Try other account or card.